# Fill table with data on submit

Tags: forms

I created a submit button in my config form.

```
$form['actions']['find_users']  = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Find users'),
        '#submit' => array('::find_users'),
      );
```

When I press on submit button, I need to create a table and fill it with the all users of my forum.

First, I created this function:

```
function find_users(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $header = [
                    'username' => t('username'),
                    'registered' => t('registered'),
                      'email' => t('e-mail'),
                    'ip' => t('ip'),
                      'last_visit' => t('last visit'),
                  ];


                  $form['table'] = array(
                    '#type' => 'tableselect',
                    '#header' => $header,
                    '#empty' => t('No users found'),
                  );
    }
```

But when I press on my submit button, table doesn't create. What should I do?

**For example**, I need to fill table with just the first record from users_field_data table (limit 1).

Comment: Depending on how many users, this is not going to be an effective way to do it. A common pattern is an admin area, an 'Import' tab, the tab displays a table (whats been imported) and a local task to kick off an update. The update is worked by a Batch API routine that generates operations for importing said users. Another way to do it would be with Migrate.

Comment: Okay, just for example, i need to fill table with just the first record from users_field_data table (limit 1)

Comment: I don't understand, are you coming into Drupal, or going out of Drupal?

Comment: I think the question is confusing because the term "table" and "fill table" is ambiguous. It also seems like your code is not complete. You don't specify where 'users' come from or how they get there. You should provide as much detail about what you're trying to accomplish (describing the end visual/data result) and how you're trying to accomplish it (code) as possible.

Comment: I want: 1) click on my submit button 2) after that, display my custom table with the headers above 3) fill this table with the real users from my forum (from users_field_data database table)

Comment: Your tableselect is missing `'#options'`. Try to stick to the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/945102) and the properties of the [tableselect](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Tableselect.php/class/Tableselect/8.2.x) element. If it still does not work after making those changes. Edit your question, explain what you have and what does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `#options` property in your `tableselect` element, e.g.

```
$form['table'] = array(
  '#type' => 'tableselect',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#multiple' => FALSE,
);
```

See: [Adding checkboxes to a table](https://www.drupal.org/node/945102).